# Level spacing as system size increases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, many-body

Why does the eigenenergies of a certain system come closer to each other as the system size increases? Is this general for all systems?

Answer (score 2):

It is more of a rule of thumb.

Let us consider two separate systems with $N_1$ and $N_2$ energy levels.
Let further $\Delta E_1$ be the difference between the highest and the lowest energy level of system 1, and $\Delta E_2$ defined analogously.
We can thus estimate the average level spacings of the two separate systems to be $\Delta E_1 / N_1$ and $\Delta E_2 / N_2$.

If the systems are brought together, they will have $N_1 N_2$ energy levels, and the energy difference between the highest and lowest level will be $\Delta E_1 + \Delta E_2$.
We estimate the average spacing to be
$$ \frac{\Delta E_1 + \Delta E_2}{N_1 N_2} , $$
which is typically much smaller than the average spacings of the individual systems.

This estimation does not account for degeneracies, though.
For example, if all spacings in system 1 are $\hbar\omega$, and all spacings in system 2 are also $\hbar\omega$, then all spacings in the combined system will also be $\hbar\omega$, but most levels will be degenerate.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be of rephrasing [Bohr's correspondence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle): as the system goes from microscopic to macroscopic, it should behave more and more as a classical system. But because classical systems do not show energy quantification, it must be that the mean spacing $\Delta E$ divided by the typical energy $E$ goes to $0$ as the size of the system increases.

At the same time, there are certain systems, such as the 1D harmonic oscillator, for which Bohr's correspondence principle is verified (at least in the form $\Delta E / E \to 0$), but the absolute spacing $\Delta E$ does not decrease (here it remains constants).

There are also systems that follow an opposite trend. For free particles in a 1D box, the energy spacing is actually $\propto \sqrt{E}$. Still we have $\Delta E / E \to 0$ but the spacing actually goes up for higher energies. I guess it also depends what you mean by "increasing the size of the system". For a fixed number of particles, if you increase the size of the box $L$, the splitting between levels is reduced everywhere (as $E \propto \frac{1}{L^2}$). However, if you take $N$ fermions in a box of fixed size $L$ and you increase N, you will probe higher and higher energy levels for which the spacing increases as $\sqrt{E}$.